# What date time datatype i should use to insert date like March2016 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

As i am trying to insert the date 'March16' which is March 2016 in mysql table x with datatype DateTime. But this gives me error incorrect date value.
Please help me . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

'`March16`' is not a correct date format. You need to do `STR_TO_DATE()` or `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Read more about above two.

If you want to insert only month and date

[Mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

> Ranges for the month and day specifiers begin with zero due to the
>   fact that MySQL permits the storing of incomplete dates such as
>   '2014-00-00'.

This means that to store the year and month only, you
can use a `DATE` column and put `00` instead of the day. e.g 2013-12-00.

Comment: Thank You very much ...but i have change the datatype from datetime to varchar

Comment: Yes. Varchar will store as you are storing a string. But my answer was for DATE datatype which you wrote in your question. :)